# How to make the subtitle without bold font?

Tags: fonts, titles

How do I make the subtitle without the bold font?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

\title{\bf{Progress Report }}
\subtitle{\Large{asdasdas}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
\setkomafont{<element>}{<commands>}
```

to set the font attributes for `<element>`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\title{Progress Report}
\subtitle{Subtitle}

\setkomafont{subtitle}{\normalfont\Large}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `\Large` (and similars) are font switches, not commands with arguments. The title is boldfaced by default. `\bf` is obsolete; you should use `\bfseries` instead.

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and `\subtitle{\Large\normalfont <element>}` ?